# ParagraphView preferrence change

Tags: java, swing

I have a JTextPane and above it a JSlider in my Swing application. When I drag the slider I want the paragraph of the JTextPane which currently has the caret to decrease/increase its width (and correspondingly adjust the height). I have implemented the following code, but nothing seems to be working. I had implemented some feature similar to this before but I think I am missing something now. Can anyone point out the mistake.

```
public class ExtendedParagraphView extends ParagraphView {
    /** Maximum width of a single char (assuming monospaced font) {#{@value}}*/
    public  static  final   float   CHARACTER_WIDTH = (float) 8.0;
    /* DELTA is used to adjust the width of the paragraph view */
    private float   DELTA = (float) 0.0;
    public ExtendedParagraphView(Element arg0) {
        super(arg0);
    }

    /**
     * Shift the paragraph to the left/right by an amount given by the 
     * difference between the end and the start position
     * @param start
     * @param end
     */
    public void shiftParagraphView (int start, int end) {
        /* The difference in pixel position is always calculated in terms of the
         * difference between the end and start position */
        DELTA = (float)(end - start) * ExtendedParagraphView.CHARACTER_WIDTH;
    }

    @Override
    public float getPreferredSpan (int axis) {
        if (axis == View.Y_AXIS) {
            return  super.getPreferredSpan(axis);
        }
        return  super.getPreferredSpan(axis) - this.DELTA;
    }
}
```

The following is the code from where it the shiftParagraphView method inside the ExtendedParagraphView is getting called.

```
protected void shiftTextPaneElement (int start, int end) {
    if (start == end) {
        return;
    }

    int dot = this.textpane.getCaret().getDot();
    int mark = this.textpane.getCaret().getMark();
    int pos = mark <= dot ? mark : dot;

    View view = textpane.getUI().getRootView(textpane);
    int n = view.getViewCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        View v = view.getView(i);
        if (v instanceof BoxView) {
            int m = v.getViewCount();
            for (int k = 0; k < m; k++) {
                View vv = v.getView(k);
                if (vv instanceof ExtendedParagraphView) {
                    ((ExtendedParagraphView) vv).
                        shiftParagraphView(start, end);
                    return; //only a single paragraph is currently shifted
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note: After some trial and error the following seems to be working,

```
public void shiftParagraphView (int start, int end) {
    DELTA = (float)(end - start) * ExtendedParagraphView.CHARACTER_WIDTH;
    this.setInsets(getTopInset(), (short) (getLeftInset() + DELTA), 
        getBottomInset(), getRightInset());
    this.getParent().preferenceChanged(this, true, false);
    this.getContainer().repaint();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `yourStyledDocument.setParagraphAttributes()` instead specifying desired left and right indent.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In fact I have seen your publically available swing codes and they are awesome. I have learned more from studying them than the Java docs. However, coming back to the question - is there no way to do this without changing the model code? I think this can be accomplished by changing the view code only. I think there is a sequence of the methods - preferrenceChanged, layout, isLayoutValid in BoxView that should do this. Here, I am only interested in changing the width of the extended paragraph view along its flow axis. I want Swing to do the adjustment along the tile axis

Comment: Definitely it's possible. preferenceChanged(...); and then repaint() should work fine. May be better to imitate Element change event.